# Separate database configuration

Tags: mysql, junit, spring-roo, entitymanager

I've been dealing with this problem for couple of days now and I can't get around to solve it. The working setup that I need is: two separate databases, one for JUnit testing and the other for the pure application access purposes.
I've been using MySQL for the the application part, since I need the full control and support and the other database that I am considering is Derby or H2 since the speed is essential here.

Okay, the MySQL database is working as it should, the JUnit tests are 100% success when I run them through
and there are no problems there. However, when I try to configure my project with the second database, the 
problems arise. I've been searching for answers and I found the following setup when adding additional database to your spring-roo project:

1. Additional ApplicationContext that I've put in: src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/ and named as: applicationContextTest.xml
2. As well as additional ApplicationContextSecurity file that I've created in the same folder and named applicationContext-securityTest.xml
3. Necessary changes in pom.xml, persistence.xml and web.xml files
4. And also I've configured @ApplicationContext in JUnit test class to use appropriate files
5. Also separate database_test.properties located in the same folder as mentioned above

The exception that I am constantly getting is that the EntityManager has not been injected. I know this is a scarce information to work on, but I just want to get few opinions before, lets say, posting the whole code and the files that go along so that you people can see if I have made some silly mistakes(which at this point I am sure I haven't) or that I am missing some additional changes that need to be made.

The configuration I am using is: latest spring roo, maven and eclipse 4.2.2

Here is the stack trace that I get for the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.entityManager_aroundBody0(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:19)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae$entityManager(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae.entityManager(ExamFormulae.java:1)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae$entityManager(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.findAllExamFormulaes_aroundBody4(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:28)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae$findAllExamFormulaes(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae.findAllExamFormulaes(ExamFormulae.java:1)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.domain.ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$eu_execom_assessmenttool_domain_ExamFormulae$findAllExamFormulaes(ExamFormulae_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
at eu.execom.assessmenttool.web.GenerateExamControllerTest.generateExamQuestions(GenerateExamControllerTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this problem before.
I have written a blog article on how to achieve this setup:

www.solubris.com/blog/overriding_spring_context_for_testing

Comment: When I try to put this piece of code: 
<util:properties id="jpaPropertyMap">
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
</util:properties> into application context i get the error: The prefix "util" for element "util:properties" is not bound. **EDIT** Nevermind, solved it with: xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" in <beans/>.

Comment: But unfortunately I am still getting the same exception. Would it help if I upload all the relevant files, maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: What @ContextConfiguration are you using?

Comment: The same one you suggested in your blog.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the environment in which I executed the roo project could not load AspectJ for some reason.

Specifically, it occurred to me when:

1. The pom.xml in eclipse give errors on the aspectj dependencies (M2E plugin execution not covered error). Solution was to do a quick fix on the error, ignore plugin goal, then set it as execute on preferences, as explained here http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered.
2. I was running the Roo project on Jetty version 8. Solution was to switch to version 9.

It maybe not your case but I hope will help others!